# cannot use having in impala

Tags: sql, select, group-by, impala, having-clause

where I use "having" in impala sql,I got an error "Could not resolve column/field reference"

```
select count(dst_ip) as times, dst_ip 
from test_mode 
group by dst_ip 
having times > 1
```

I don't konw why, impala document is support having
https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_group_by.html#group_by

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few databases support reusing aliases defined in the `select` in the `having` clause (MySQL comes to mind). I don't think that this belongs to standard ANSI SQL .

In most other databses, such as Impala, you need to repeat the expression:

```
select count(dst_ip) as times, dst_ip 
from test_mode 
group by dst_ip 
having count(dst_ip) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your impala version, move to upper directory and find right document.
https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/

For example, Apache Impala Guide(impala-3.4.pdf) says, in `Overview of Impala Aliases`:

> From Impala 3.0, the alias substitution logic in the GROUP BY, HAVING, and ORDER BY clauses has become more consistent with standard SQL behavior, as follows. Aliases are now only legal at the top level, and not in subexpressions. The following statements are allowed:

```
SELECT int_col / 2 AS x  FROM t  GROUP BY x;
SELECT int_col / 2 AS x  FROM t  ORDER BY x;
SELECT NOT bool_col AS nb  FROM t  GROUP BY nb  HAVING nb;
```

> And the following statements are NOT allowed:

```
SELECT int_col / 2 AS x  FROM t  GROUP BY x / 2;
SELECT int_col / 2 AS x  FROM t  ORDER BY -x;
SELECT int_col / 2 AS x  FROM t  GROUP BY x HAVING x > 3;
```

In your sql, `times > 1` is a subexpression and `having times > 1` is unacceptable in Impala 3.0 or later.